# ASP.NET - what files store method signature for xml web service?

Tags: asp.net

i find this question tricky but what files store method signature info for xml webservice?
.dll, .asmx, .wsdl, .disco ?

TIA

Comment: Can you be more specific? What type of xml web service are you talking about? .NET web services? Using what framework, WCF of ASMX/WSE? When you say method signature, are you talking about the service implementation's method signature, or an xml description of the methods in the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes into a DLL once compiled, but it's in a code file when added to the project (referred to as a proxy class, it's in whatever language your project is).  When you add a web reference it's imported this way.  Updating the reference updates the .cs (or vb, whatever you're using).

If you want to see what happens, you can generate the code file yourself, [see MSDN for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.80).aspx).

So overall:  It is WSDL when fetched, converted to a code file when included (or updated), then finally compiled with the rest of your code into the DLL.

Comment: i thought of .wsdl but your explanation seems right, so it must be .dll

Comment: @Wisdom, just depends what part of the lifecycle you're looking at I guess, but in the final application yes that's right...otherwise how could code call it?  The code referencing that signature has to be compiled after all.